# Mule - How to aggregate results from foreach and return the results?

Tags: collections, foreach, mule, aggregator

I am new to Mule and here is what I am trying to do.
1) Call a outbound rest service A
2) loop through the results and call rest service B
3) aggregate results from service B and return the payload.
Here is what I came up with, but this flow is returning results from service A. How can Ignore result from A and return aggregated result from B? I added logger inside for loop and can see the response from B, but not sure how to return the result back to user? Do I need custom aggregator?

```
<flow name="test1Flow1" doc:name="test1Flow1">   

    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" doc:name="HTTP1" address="http://localhost:8082"/>
        <copy-properties propertyName="*" doc:name="Property"/>
        <http:outbound-endpoint doc:name="HTTP2" followRedirects="true" address="http://abcd/catalog/#[message.inboundProperties['http.relative.path']]?#[message.inboundProperties['http.query.string']]" contentType="text/xml"/>

    <foreach doc:name="For Each" collection="#[xpath('//mc:assets/mc:asset')]">

    <http:outbound-endpoint doc:name="HTTP3" address="http://abcd#[xpath:@href]" contentType="text/xml" method="GET"/>
    <collection-aggregator failOnTimeout="true" doc:name="Collection Aggregator"/>        
    </foreach>

</flow>
```

Appreciate any help !

Answer (score 0):

The foreach in Mule works like a loop and acts like a splitter and aggregator at once.

I believe that you will be able to achieve your use case with the following:

1. in http
2. out http A
3. splitter
4. out http B
5. aggregator

have a look [here](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Routing+Message+Processors#RoutingMessageProcessors-Splitter) for examples of the splitter and aggregator.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do something very similar and I ended up using a collection-splitter, collection-aggregator combination. Look here for details: [In Mule how do you repeatedly call a webservice and return an aggregate of the result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20766859/in-mule-how-do-you-repeatedly-call-a-webservice-and-return-an-aggregate-of-the-r)