# In Mule how do you repeatedly call a webservice and return an aggregate of the result?

Tags: mule

I am trying to achiEve the following in Mule:

1. Call webservice A
2. receive json array as response
3. transform json array in to an ArrayList
4. Call webservice B for each entry in the arraylist
5. Aggregate results from all the calls in step 4

My question is, what is the right way of doing this:

a) foreach loop
b) collection-aggregator-router
c) some other way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out by trial and error. I thought I will update this question for anyone else who lands on this page.

This is what worked for me:

```
<flow-ref name="Webservice-A" />        
<collection-splitter enableCorrelation="ALWAYS" />
<flow-ref name="Webservice-B" />
<collection-aggregator />
```

Webservice-A returns a list, the collection splitter takes the items from the list and calls Webservice-B for each item on the list, and then the collection-aggregator puts the results back together.